# Get a Firestore document which matches as many values as possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app, which allows users to specify their skills and interests, and then get suggested jobs, based on their skills and interests.

Both are stored in a user document as an array:

```
skills: ['computers', 'blah-blah']

interests: ['whatever']
```

Each job is also stored in Firestore with a skills and an interests array (specified by the creator).

My question is, what would be the best way to find a job document which matches as many skills and interests as possible, based on the user making the request?

Comment: Did you already check the Firebase documentation on [querying Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and its [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)?

Comment: Firestore has [`array-contains-any`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any) operator that can query jobs that have at least one of the skills in the document but there isn't any direct way to sort the document by matching elements count. Also you can only use 1 `array-contains-any` clause per query so the interests would most likely be another query.

Comment: Firestore doesn't have any "best fit" queries that rank documents like a search engine based on some sort of relevancy score.  Firestore only matches exact contents based on your query filters.  You tell it what exactly you're looking for, and it tells you the documents that match.  If you're looking for multiple things that might or might not be present, you will have to make separate queries for each of those things, and decide in your app which is "best".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like what Frank and Dharmaraj already stated in the comments, I suggest that you further check the [`array-contains-any`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any), for example:

```
import { query, where } from "firebase/firestore";  

const skillsQuery = query(skillsRef, 
  where('skills', 'array-contains-any', ['computers', 'blah-blah']));

const interestsQuery = query(interestsRef, 
  where('interests', 'array-contains-any', ['whatever', 'etc']));
```

Just note the following [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations_2) of `array-contains-any`:

- `array-contains-any` support up to 10 comparison values.
- You can use at most one in, not-in, or array-contains-any clause per query. You can't combine these operators in the same query.
- If you have more than 10 UIDs, you'll have to still do multiple queries and merge the results client-side.